# What type of interpolation should be used in key rate perturbation models?

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates

When perturbing a key rate in order to assess sensitivity of portfolio value, what sort of interpolation is standard? A book I am looking at says linear, but this seems pretty unrealistic to me--and of real significance for longer durated portfolios or shorter term perturbations. Anyone familiar with literature on the matter? Thanks.

Comment: Please add a link or a reference.

Answer (score -1):

If I have understand right what you are looking for, I think that Nelson–Siegel Model can halp you, google it.

Hear some readng: [Nelson-Siegel model](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/jbes.2009.07295)